# How do I narrow a union of string and Regex?

Tags: typescript

If I define a type like this: `type Name = string | Regex` and pass it into a function, what is the *TypeScript* way to discover which type was passed?

It's easy to find answers to this for JavaScript, but I'm struggling any for TypeScript. Maybe that's because the answers are one and the same, but I'm hoping there is a compile-time way of checking.

Comment: It's going to be the same as javascript. `foo instanceof RegExp` to check for regex, `typeof foo === 'string'` to check for string.

Comment: @NicholasTower Ah. That's disappointing. Feel free to write what you said as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript doesn't have any special ways to narrow down types. You need to use regular javascript to narrow down the types, and if you do typescript will deduce that inside `if` statements (and other control statements), the type can only be one possible type.

So to check whether something is a string you can use `typeof foo === "string"`, and to check for a regular expression you can check for `foo instanceof RegExp`.

```
type Name = string | RegExp;

const test: Name = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'hi' : /ab+c/;

if (typeof test === 'string') {
  console.log(test.toUpperCase());
}

if (test instanceof RegExp) {
  console.log(test.flags);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigZ2AJwJYDsDmUAPlAEoT4CiAHmANwBQDAxgPa4ZTAQYBcsiFFACycYAAsAdJji4AJqwRQAFAEooAPigAGSQFYoAfigBycdhNR%20AejgAjANTNrjBtgBmK0JFafunZEDTDBwCE3UAbwYoKDYOVgAbCEkE1nxlf2BJYFYAVTBITABhODQINVVGAF8mDy8eYCg8DFlmCF8yChowSOjY9jRE5NT0zMl3BLh8NEqGKqA)

Comment: I just found a blog article that lists all the other ways to do it: https://www.carlrippon.com/6-ways-to-narrow-types-in-typescript/  Is the real way of narrowing these two types down using the `in` keyword?

Comment: `Is the real way of narrowing these two types down using the in keyword?` These two? No. But it can be useful for narrowing down other types.